# How can I have SQL Server retain security audits to a max size but then remove the oldest and keep going?

Tags: sql-server, audit, splunk

Whenever I try to set a limit for SQL Server audits it stops when it hits the max. I want it to keep going forever, but only retain so much. What is the correct way to accomplish this? Splunk doesn't seem to like having multiple files when I pull in the data in DB Connect. But even roll over files seem to stop once the max number of files is hit.